# Caching with static sites - nanoc

Tags: caching, nanoc

I am using nanoc for one of my sites. I am wondering is there a way to do some good caching for the website. because everytime i update the page i need to hard refresh or refresh couple of times to have changes updated on the browser.

What should i do in order to have the page load the current content right after the first refresh ?

thanks

Comment: I suspect this depends on the caching configuration of your server, I don't recall seeing this behavior with Safari and the default Apache on a Mac…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it, this is not a nanoc question but more of a question related to the configuration of either your web server or your browser. Double-check your ETag, Last-Modified and Cache-Control headers. If I recall correctly, Firefox (still) caches aggressively, so that may explain your problem.